# Make a curve in Border using CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to make a curve in a border.. Like that when u click on a google apps button A pop-up window is open here is curve which point to the apps.. how to make this see the image..
[image: IMAGE IS HERE]

Comment: http://cssarrowplease.com/

Comment: you are probably trying to do something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/xfVeh/

Comment: Can u explain this code little more...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use pseudo elements to produce the triangle.

We can give a border to the triangle by using both the before and after pseudo elements - which act as 2 triangles - an outer one - with a color the same as the border color and an inner one - with a slight offset - with a color the same as the background of the widget.

In the following example, the before pseudo element is the 'outer' triangle and the after pseudo elemnt is the 'inner' triangle.

### Markup

```
<p class="triangle-border">This only needs one HTML element.</p>
```

### CSS

```
.triangle-border {
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 20px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
.triangle-border:before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: 46px;
    border-width: 0 10px 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #c2c2c2 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    display: block;
    width: 0;
}
.triangle-border:after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    top: -8px;
    left: 47px;
    border-width: 0 9px 9px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #FFF rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    display: block;
    width: 0;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vAjQP/1/)**

Source: http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/demo/

There are also generators for this like:

http://ilikepixels.co.uk/drop/bubbler/

http://cssarrowplease.com

http://html-generator.weebly.com/css-speech-bubble-generator.html

Comment: The OP is probably going to blindly copy and paste this. Perhaps explaining the solution will provide more use to future readers?

Comment: @JimmyBreck-McKye - I added an explanation

Comment: Cool. Do you think the question title should be edited so it's maybe a bit more findable? I'd do it myself but I don't have the rep

Answer (score 0):

The usual method is to add before and after pseudo-elements that create CSS shapes using the border property, positioning them absolutely. If you want to fake a 'border' on the shape itself, you create two duplicate shapes (the before and after elements) with different colours, then offset them with the top or left properties.